# Redirect http to https for cpanel

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I want to redirect http://cpanel.domain.com to https://cpanel.domain.com what can i do?

I tried this but its not working for cPanel it just working for domain.com :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is what you need for redirecting `HTTP` to `HTTPS`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: What is your complete `htaccess`?

Comment: what do you mean do you mean what the full of code i write in my htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

add this code into .htaccess file

---

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]